# Is there a list of all of Abarbanel’s questions on the Torah?

Tags: commentaries, pentateuch-chumash, abarbanel

I was wondering if anyone has this by itself compiled as a tool for learning the Parsha. I want to go over each question and look at the mefarshim.

Comment: Doesn't he list them at the beginning of each parsha? Should take 10 minutes for someone with access to Bar Ilan Respona to copy paste it all.